# mysql requests logic

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 table 
and 2 values

display.isUpload = 2

userId = 11 (current userId)

First

```
Table Ask
id INT
userId INT
qask VARCHAR
```

Second

```
 Table Display
    id INT
    askId INT
    isUpload INT
```

Third

```
Table Push

    id INT
    displayId INT
    userId INT
```

The logic ask display as a list of asks, when user select one of them it will record to table push. 
Now i need to display all record from ask, but not records that user add to push (i do not not how to do this in my current request) and display.isUploaded = 2 and that ask.userId  NOT IN 11. (i can't delete records from ask)
My current sql request

```
                  SELECT
  a.id as id,
  a.qask as qask
  FROM Ask AS a
  JOIN Display AS d ON d.askId = a.id
  WHERE d.isUploaded = 2 AND
   a.userId  NOT IN (11)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that user add to push"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want this (I added the final row):

```
SELECT
  a.id as id,
  a.qask as qask
  FROM Ask AS a
  JOIN Display AS d ON d.askId = a.id
  WHERE d.isUploaded = 2 AND
   a.userId  NOT IN (11)
  AND a.userId NOT IN ( SELECT id from Push)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear, from what i understood i wrote this query

```
SELECT
a.id AS id,
a.qask AS qask
FROM Ask AS a
LEFT JOIN Display AS d ON d.askId = a.id
LEFT JOIN Push AS p ON p.displayId = d.id
WHERE d.isUploaded = 2 
AND p.id=NULL
AND a.userId <>11
```